# Using a single set of random number generators in a loop

Tags: c, math, random, embedded, distribution

Given the code below, is it possible to modify it so that there's a single set of `M` "random" numbers for `x` and `y` that will "restart" at the beginning of the set for every iteration of `i`?

What I know I can do is pre-generate an array for `x` and `y` of length `M` but I cannot use arrays because of limited memory. I was thinking of using random numbers with seeds somehow but haven't been able to figure it out.

```
double sampleNormal()
{
   double u = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;
   double v = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;
   double r = u * u + v * v;
   if (r == 0 || r > 1) return sampleNormal();
   double c = sqrt(-2 * log(r) / r);
   return u * c;
}
```

...

```
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
double a = 0;
double f = 100e6;
double t = 0;
double fsamp = 2e9;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        x = sampleNormal();
        y = sampleNormal();
        t = j/fsamp;

        a = x*cos(2*pi*f*t)+y*sin(2*pi*f*t);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the objective of this program? When `rand()` value is too big for your purpose, then generally `mod` (remainder `%` in `C`) is taken for even distribution of values.

Comment: the objective is to generate a bunch sinusoids with random amplitudes. Its not that the value of `rand()` is too big, it's that I need `M` values of `rand()` and i cannot fit `M` `x`'s and `y`'s because of limited space.

Comment: `double c = sqrt(-2 * log(r) / r);` doesn't that yield a complex number?

Comment: no because log(r) < 0

Comment: Right, I overlooked that `if` condition just above.

Comment: You want to use `N` times same `(x, y)` values from a set of size `M`?

Comment: i want to generate `M` x's and `M` y's and use them for every `i`

Comment: Since you tagged this embedded, are you using a RTC? Where are the random numbers coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> that will "restart" at the beginning of the set for every iteration of i

> was thinking of using random numbers with seeds somehow but haven't been able to figure it out.

Code could abuse `srand()`

```
// Get some state info from rand() for later.
unsigned start = rand();
start = start*(RAND_MAX + 1u) + rand();

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  // Initialize the random number generator to produce the same sequence.
  srand(42);  // Use your favorite constant.
  for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    x = sampleNormal();
    y = sampleNormal();
    t = j/fsamp;

    a = x*cos(2*pi*f*t)+y*sin(2*pi*f*t);
  }
}

// Re-seed so other calls to `rand()` are not so predictable.
srand(start);
```

Comment: The `random` paradox, nice one.

Comment: @SparKot Instead of `rand()`, we could use [nine](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).